# jQuery toggle css messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using jquery toggle function to show or hide a div using css disply, but its getting messy when i toggle it shows div but when I wanted to hide it it also cuts my top bar aswell.

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    var e = $(this).attr("href"),
        n = $(this);
    $(e).toggle(function() {
        n.html("none" == $(this).css("display") ? "Links" : "Close")
    })
});
```

heres the link [Link of my website](https://tvseriesden.com/movie/deadpool) when you open and click on links button it will show the links but my top menu will cut of.

Heres the toggle trigger

```
<a href="#collapse1" class="toggle">Links</a>
```

Comment: your website seems to be working just fine.. What is the problem? Top menu is also working fine and not getting cut on click of links

Comment: @Reddy look at the Screenshot https://gyazo.com/a250133efc2461ae243c85ca820cc1de

Comment: This is what I see in my machine... http://imgur.com/szdv7YB  I am using Chrome. May be your css is not browser compatible.. have a check

Comment: can you try and check this link its also mine http://watch32.ag/movie/hardcore-henry

Comment: just figured it out forgot to set min-height for the section.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know... :) gad you fixed the issue...

Comment: thank you for your time @Reddy

Answer (score 0):

just figured it out forgot to set min-height for the section.